# color grading on white background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, color

I am doing a video in blender with two versions, one in black background and one with white background. The problem is with the white one because it feels like the white color reflect on objects and make it brighter and I need the background to be 100% white. 
I applied the white color from the world panel>Background>color>Pure white and the color type is Filmic. 
Is the problem with the way of making the background or I can grad it in better way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: World background affects the color of the objects' materials if their shaders allow color changings after light bounces (diffuse, glossy shaders etc) which can make materials look flat. You can render scene on whatever world environment you setup (procedural sky, hdri map etc) with transparent background and then add white background in compositing.

Comment: What you call "pure white" needs a brighter value if you are using filmic blender. I would suggest that instead of using the world background, you add the background in the compositor. To get "pure white" you would need the values of the background to be close to 17

Comment: Hi guys and thanks. Now I am trying to render one without diffuse and glossy ray visibility. I would try also the transparent background it looks good enough to solve my problem. I tried with background in compositor but I think I did not match that value 17.